# VBS syntax error with errorlevel

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, operating-system, syntax-error, arrow-keys

Today I decided to start making a simple batch OS and it has working great so far login and create account are finished but then I tested it again and I keeping getting a syntax error at 
:login -- the location of the error levels

`````
    @echo off
    cls
    :startup
    color 17
    echo                                                  
    echo        ```                                       
    echo       .//:            .`                         
    echo    :////`            -os.                        
    echo    :////````           :s`                       
    echo     ```:////-  .::::::::o-    `....`             
    echo   ...  -////-  osssssssss//osssssssss+:          
    echo  `///`  ````   ossssssssssssssssssssssso`        
    echo          .oooooo.....:sssssssssssssssssss`       
    echo          :sssss+     .sssssssssssssssssss+ 
    echo          :sssss+     .sssssssssssssssssss+      
    echo    -///- -sssss+`    -ssssssssssssssssssso       
    echo    -///:-`    `sssssssssssssssssssssssssso       
    echo       -::.     osssssssssssssssssssssssss:       
    echo            `-.    +ssssssssssssssssssssso        
    echo            :so    +sssssssssssssssssssss.
    echo            :so    +sssssssssssssssssssss.        
    echo            :sssooosssssssssssssssssssss.         
    echo             +sssssssssssssssssssssssso.          
    echo              -ssssssssssssssssssssss/            
    echo               `/ssssssssssssssssss+. 
    echo               `/ssssssssssssssssss+.            
    echo                  -/osso/  /+sss+:`     
    timeout 6 > NULL
    goto login

    :login
    cls
    echo |  USE ARROW KEYS TO SELECT  |
    echo |          -------           |
    echo |        UP>Login<UP         |
    echo |          -------           |
    echo | DOWN> Create Account <DOWN |
    echo |          -------           |
    If errorlevel 72 goto logsin
    If errorlevel 80 goto createaccount
    SET /P 0=0
    if not defined 0 goto login
    end if
`````

Comment: Try to avoid the pipe `|` and redirect `>` `<` operators, even within the `echo`s - as that will mess things up! Try other characters instead.

Comment: Your code is batch and has nothing to do with VBScript. Except perhaps the trailing `end if`, which is not a valid statement in batch.

Comment: Worst researched question ever?

Comment: 'Batch' ... 'OS' ... pick one

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the `|<>` with a `^` caret like this `echo ^|^<^>`

The `set /p` command isn't going to register an up or down arrow though

The timeout command is creating a file called NULL.  Use `nul` for the nul device.